# execute a function after fadeOut() done in an another function

Tags: jquery

I am creating a page where I have created two functions: one is for fadeOut-fadeIn and another is for changing the view of layouts.

I want to change the view only when the fadeOut-fadeIn function is done.

```
$someTarget.click(function(){
//all actions here once the below function done
});

$someTarget2.click(function(){
    $subtarget.fadeOut();
    $subtarget.fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Trying reading the jQuery documentation. It will blow your mind.

Comment: Deferred to the rescue, http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/  and http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery

Comment: thanks Mark...this could be the solution... i will have to check

Answer (score 0):

```
$(subtarget).fadeOut(function(){
   $(someTarget).trigger('click');
});
```

Edit:

```
$someTarget.live(‘click’, function(){
//all actions here once the below function done
});

$someTarget2.click(function(){
    $subtarget.fadeOut(function(){
       $subtarget.fadeIn(function(){
           $someTarget.trigger('click');
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer... can you please write complete code, where to put this code...thanks

Comment: Assuming that You want to fadeOut, then fadeIn, then trigger someTarget click event, edited.

Comment: There's no need to use callbacks.  Animations automatically chain.

Comment: don't need to start with in the fadeOut itself.. 

$someTarget.live(‘click’, ... this would be the function where I have to fire the onclick function if fadeOut-fadeIn done....


many thanks for your support guys..

Answer (score 0):

You can chain your driver function, then use the callback component:

```
$someTarget2.click(function(){
    $subtarget
        .fadeOut()
        .fadeIn(function(){
            $someTarget.click(function(){
                // magic actions here
            }); 
        });
});
```

Or just trigger the click component:

```
$someTarget2.click(function(){
    $subtarget
        .fadeOut()
        .fadeIn(function(){
            $someTarget.trigger('click');
        });
});
```

Just as a heads up, the way you've written the `.fadeIn` and .`fadeOut` pieces means they will run at the same time... if u want to do a "flash" like thing (which I think is what you want?) you need to chain them so they run sequentially.

Comment: don't need to start with in the fadeOut itself.. 

$someTarget.live(‘click’, ... this would the function where I have to fire the onclick function if fadeOut-fadeIn done....


many thanks for your support guys..

Comment: just a heads up, `.live()` is deprecated, has been for a long time. you should use `.on()` instead, if you arent using the shorthand (`.click()` is shorthand for `.on('click')`).

Comment: @Mufeed - the larger problem is twofold. one, your question is ambiguously and poorly described, and so you get a wealth of answers that don't solve your problem because you don't describe accurately what the problem is. two, you have failed to perform the most basic of documentation reading, which immediately sets you up for failure. the solution is for you to read the documentation, then more appropriately describe your problem

Comment: … Thanks for your efforts...I think you didn't get the question well... question is quite clearer even in the title… 
"execute a function after fadeOut() done in an another function"

Comment: obviously, thats why you have an answer at this point. regardless, good luck in your endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callbacks in `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`

```
$someTarget2.click(function(){
    $subtarget.fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $subtarget.fadeIn("fast", function() {
            //done fading in, change your view here
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: don't need to start with in the fadeOut itself.. 

$someTarget.live(‘click’, ... this would be the function where I have to fire the onclick function if fadeOut-fadeIn done....


many thanks for your support guys..

Answer (score 0):

```
$someTarget2.click(function(){
    $someTarget.fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow',function(){
       // change view here
    });
});
```

Comment: @FlashThunder That's fine.  The animations will chain.  What's wrong with it?

Comment: @FlashThunder We all do it.  Have some coffee :)

Comment: don't need to start with in the fadeOut itself.. 

$someTarget.live(‘click’, ... this would be the function where I have to fire the onclick function if fadeOut-fadeIn done....


many thanks for your support guys..